# Linked List, not adding values properly

Tags: java

I'm currently working on my assignment which is to implement the LinkedList data structure, I have all my code finished except that it's not properly working, the input code which I'm testing it with is "1,2,3,4,5", however only "1" is being outputted instead of all of the values.

Here's my code:

```
// Main Method Functions
private static LinkedList createLinkedList(int[] values) {
    LinkedList list;

    list = new LinkedList();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        list.add(values[i]);
    }
    return list;
}

private static void printList(LinkedList list) {
    Node currentNode = list.getHead();

    while(currentNode != null) {
        System.out.println(currentNode.getint());
        currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    }
}

// LinkedList class functions
public void add(int value) {
    Node newNode = new Node(value);
    Node currentNode;

    if(head == null) {
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        currentNode = newNode;

        while(currentNode.getNextNode() != null) {
            currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
        }
        currentNode.setNextNode(newNode);
    }
    size++;
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Let me know if you need any other functions added in, thanks.

EDIT: The function which shows the values being added:

```
private static void processLinkedList() {
    int[] values = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    LinkedList list = createLinkedList(values);
    printList(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description. Please elaborate.

Comment: you need to be more specific. How is it not working properly? what did you do to test it? where do you think the problem is?

Comment: Right sorry, my input values to test with are "1,2,3,4,5" however only "1" is being outputted.

Comment: Can we see how "values" is declared?

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the relevant code. It is in your interest to provide the minimal compilable code that presents the error (and, in the process of producing this code, you usually will solve your problem on your own...)

Comment: In add() you set currentNode to the newNode and then try to traverse to the end.  CurrentNode should be set to the head, then traverse, and add newNode to the end.

Comment: I added in the process function that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `add()` method,

```
currentNode = newNode;
```

should likely be changed to

```
currentNode = head;
```

See if that moves you forward.

Comment: Awesome!  Be sure to accept whatever answer satisfies your question.

Answer (score 1):

you probably should replace 
else {
        currentNode = newNode;
by
else {
        currentNode = head;